# Is it possible to access Google App Engine from Android without Google APIs?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, android-source, android-build

So I have downloaded source code(AOSP) for Android 4.4.2, built it and of course there is no Google APIs or Google Play Servicies, but I want to include there Android app using Google App Engine Cloud Storage and Google Account authentification system.

Is it somehow possible?

Or is it possible to get Android 4.4.2 source code (for personal use only) with Google APIs from google inc.?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about Auth with Endpoints? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth
I hope this help you.
Can you explain more  about "personal use only"

Comment: Yes I know, but it is possible to use endpoints from Android device (emulator) without Google APIs?